# pm2 --interpreter option not working through script

Tags: node.js, bash, pm2, nvm

I'm running a script to start a pm2 process with a specific version of node.

My script is something like that:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
export NVM_DIR=$HOME/.nvm;
source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh;

npx pm2 flush
npx pm2 kill

echo "starting service"
pushd ./my-service || exit
nvm use 12.22.5
which node # prints <home>/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.5/bin/node
which pm2 # prints <home>/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.5/bin/pm2
node -v # prints v12.22.5
pm2 -v # prints 5.1.2
npx pm2 start pm2.config.js --env local --interpreter="<home>/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.5/bin/node" --watch 2>&1
popd || exit
npx pm2 logs
```

However, when I print `process.version` in the app, it shows v14.17.4 - which is the version used in the shell outside the script.
(pm2 runs the process in cluster mode)

Comment: `--interpreter` parameter only works in `fork_mode` so it's probably the cluster mode which is causing the issue.